# Simultaneous connection in Blaze plan of firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know that does blaze plan of firebase gives 100k simultaneous connection for free ?

Answer (score 0):

The blaze plan uses metered pricing. As long as you stay within the free quota as shown on the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), you will not be charged for your usage. If you go over the free quota, you will be charged the amounts that are shown on that same page.

The pricing is based on the amount of data stored and the outgoing bandwidth consumed, not on the number of simultaneous connections. In other words: it doesn't matter if 100,000 users consume 1Kb each, or a single user consumes 100 Mb, the charge will be the same.

Comment: But I m a bit confused bcz the spark plan have limit of 100 simultaneous connections while the flame plan have 100k . But I don't know how many simultaneous connections are allowed for free in the Blaze plan .

Comment: There is no charge on the number of connections.